Custom sorting function for TanStack Table not working as expected
I'm using TanStack Table with React and I'm trying to implement a custom sorting function for the "status" column. I want to sort the status in a specific order like so: 'none' -> 'single'  -> 'complicated'  ->'relationship' then repeat. I want it to cycle through this order
However, my current implementation is not working as expected (as I want). When I trigger the re-order, seems like i'm getting 'none' -> 'single' -> 'relationship' -> 'none' which is not the behavior i want bcs it does miss the complicated status
This is the function
const sortStatusFn: SortingFn<Person> = (rowA, rowB, _columnId) => {
  const statusA = rowA.original.status;
  const statusB = rowB.original.status;
  const statusOrder = ['single', 'complicated', 'relationship'];
  return statusOrder.indexOf(statusA) - statusOrder.indexOf(statusB);
};

You can experement with the example I have on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/tanstack-table-d8955d?file=src%2Fmain.tsx,src%2FmakeData.ts,src%2Findex.css&preset=node
Questions:

How can I modify the custom sorting function to correctly cycle through all three status values 'none' -> 'single'  -> 'complicated'  ->'relationship' in the desired order?
How can I make the function scalable to handle more than three status values?

I apologize if I've missed any important details or if my question isn't clear - this is my first time posting on Stack Overflow, and I appreciate your patience and guidance.

The React Table documentation outlines the type definition for ColumnSort:


export type ColumnSort = {
  id: string
  desc: boolean
}



Even if you pass a custom sort function that manually manipulates the values from 'none'->'single'->'relationship'->'none', what would the desc value be set to in the case that complicated is the value that we are currently sorting on? There would always be a discrepancy between what your sortingFn is keeping in state and what the table instance has in its state.
At least according to the API definition of sorting, what you are doing here isn't 'sorting' the rows. Thinking outside of this context, I can't think of any examples on the internet where a sorting button shuffles through a list of available values in a customized order, instead of ordering by some other criterion in ascending or descending order.
I would reconsider whether this is something that might be handled by using the filtering API. This seems like a misuse of the sorting API in react table.

thnks @jamesTobey, I got your point about the 'none' -> 'desc' -> 'asc' -> 'none'  but setting enableSortingRemoval to false is still not showing the complicated status order, now i'm getting 'signle' -> 'relationship'.
I'm looking for away, to get this order 'none' -> 'single'  -> 'complicated'  ->'relationship' and then repeat
